# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$dbConn'

Tags: php, database

I have the error unexpected $dbConn when I run this code, 
but I did wrote the code for $dbConn and I have no idea why....

here my user.php with login database and users table.

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME','login');
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

class User{
  $dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
  $dbConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


  public function Login($name, $password){
    if(!empty($name) && !empty($password)){
      $statement = $dbConn->prepare("select * from users where name=? and password=?");
      $statement->bindParam(1, $name);
      $statement->bindParam(2, $password);
      $statement->execute();

      if($statement->rowCount() == 1){
        echo "User verified, Access granted.";
      }else{
        echo "Incorrect username or password";
      }
    }else{
      echo "Please enter username and password";
    }

  }


}


 ?>
```

Below are the index.php

```
<?php

include_once('user.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $name     = $_POST['user'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $object = new User();
  $object->Login($name, $password);
}


 ?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="index.php">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user">
    Password: <input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me with my problem?
Thanks and appreciate alot.

Comment: Sidenote: The code you posted in regards to passwords; is this live or meant to go in a live environment as is? You realize that that isn't safe even with a prepared statement.

Comment: Try putting the code defining the $dbConn inside the login function, just for testing sake, to see if it works. Then, may be it is a scope issue. You may have to use global $dbConn or something equivalent inside the function, if $dbConn is declare outside it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have executable code outside a method in a class like this:

```
class User
{

  $dbConn = new PDO(...);
  $dbConn->setAttribute(...);

  public function Login($name, $password){
  }

}
```

If you want to initialize something you can use a constructor:

```
class User
{

  protected $dbConn;

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->dbConn = new PDO(...);
      $this->dbConn->setAttribute(...);
  }

}
```